# tcp checksum calculate как?

Tags: linux, kernel

Для написания балансировщика сети, мне нужно рассчитать хэш сумму TCP в Kernel mode. Облазил кучу интернета, но так и не понял как это сделать.
Как мне узнать tcp_length?
Есть пример, и считает TCP хэш, о при этом браузер пишет DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_BAD_CONFIG. Хэш на выходе получается одинаковый.

```
printk(KERN_ALERT "INFO: CHECKSUM TCP old: %u.\n",tcph->check);
datalen = skb->len - (iph->ihl << 2);
tcph->check = 0;printk(KERN_ALERT "INFO: CHECKSUM TCP=0: %u.\n",tcph->check);
tcph->check = csum_tcpudp_magic(iph->saddr, iph->daddr, datalen, IPPROTO_TCP, csum_partial((unsigned char *)tcph,datalen,0));
printk(KERN_ALERT "INFO: CHECKSUM TCP new: %u.\n",tcph->check);
```

Ещё команда ping пишет

```
    64 bytes from 192.168.137.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=128 time=0.304 ms
wrong data byte #8 should be 0x8 but was 0x73
#8  73 dc a b c d e f 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 1a 1b 1c 1d 1e 1f 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 
#40 28 29 2a 2b 2c 2d 2e 2f 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37
```

Что не так я делаю?

Comment: А какое отношение имеет контрольная сумма TCP к некому поврежденному ICMP пакету (ping работает через ICMP, он никакого отношения к TCP не имеет, это отдельный протокол одинакового с ним уровня)

Comment: При этом DNS (на который ругается браузер) работает по протоколу UDP, который так же ни разу не TCP

Comment: Точно! Я забыл про протоколы! Спасибо ! Получается что я хэшировал всегда с одним и тем же протоколом.

Comment: Все-таки неправильно считает хэш сумму. tcph->check = csum_tcpudp_magic(iph->saddr, iph->daddr, datalen, IPPROTO_TCP, csum_partial((unsigned char *)tcph,datalen,0));  не могу понять, как правильно рассчитывать datalen

Comment: не пойму зачем так изголяться. балансировщики делаются меткой маршрута

Comment: Мне нужно свою систему сделать через мучения, дипломная работа

Comment: 'skb->ip_summed = CHECKSUM_UNNECESSARY;' - добавил после расчета суммы, сумма отличная от старой, но пакеты идут..
Правильно ли я понимаю, что skb->ip_summed = CHECKSUM_UNNECESSARY; - позволяет не обращать внимания на чексумму?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
printk(KERN_ALERT "INFO: CHECKSUM TCP old: %u.\n",tcph->check);
datalen = skb->len - (iph->ihl << 2);  
tcph->check = 0;
tcph->check = csum_tcpudp_magic(iph->saddr, iph->daddr,datalen, iph->protocol,csum_partial((char *)tcph, datalen, 0));
skb->ip_summed = CHECKSUM_UNNECESSARY;
printk(KERN_ALERT "INFO: CHECKSUM TCP new: %u.\n",tcph->check);
```

skb->ip_summed = CHECKSUM_UNNECESSARY - добавил, работает все, т.е. TCP checksum пересчитывает и принимается ОС